# How to create Extjs app that works on iPhone, iPad and Android?

Tags: android, iphone, ajax, extjs

Has anyone successfully created an Extjs app that works on iPhone, iPad and Android?  I know that Sencha doesn't support Extjs on mobile devices, but I don't want to create another website just for mobile.  I don't need fanciful mobile interface, just basic functionality.

I did some quick tests.  For a start, I managed to make the interface larger using

The original interface was too small on an iPhone screen. However, even though the interface has become larger, auto sizing seem to stop working properly, for example, the grid does not display entirely when using the Portrait orientation.

Another thing, scrollbars are missing for grid. I'm still searching for a solution. Is it possible to add external buttons to act as scrollers?

Also, you may suggest an alternative tool to Extjs that works for both mobile and PC.

Thanks for any pointers. :)

Comment: @Amalea: Thanks, I didn't notice the check outline all this while, so I just commented on whichever solution worked. As for my question, what I am asking is if it is possible to create an extjs application that can work on iPhone and Android, and if so what are the common tweaks required.

Comment: I made some edits to the original question, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternative to ExtJS that works on all the devices specified: [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/).

It is Sencha's ( the company that does ExtJs ) answer to the fact that ExtJS doesn't work (well ) on mobile devices, and is built specifically for touch devices, using similar concepts as extjs.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Due to budget and time constraint, I'm trying to avoid creating a dedicated site just for mobile devices.

Comment: I should point out that if you are on a tight schedule, hacking extjs to work on a mobile device is probably not a practical solution. Likely you will have a very hard time getting any RIA framework that is native to both platforms.

Comment: you're right. I'm considering another solution altogether. It is too troublesome to code twice.

Comment: Am now considering JQuery instead.

Comment: If you are talking about jQuery UI, thats back to square 1 I believe. (Coz jQuery mobile is to jQuery UI as Sencha touch is to ExtJs)