# Extjs 4 mobile and tablet support

Tags: extjs

I found a single thread on this issue, but there was no solution for me. And it's been 4 years since the thread was created, so I thought maybe someone might have come up with an acceptable "hack" in the meantime.

The thread I found:
[How to create Extjs app that works on iPhone, iPad and Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598118/how-to-create-extjs-app-that-works-on-iphone-ipad-and-android)

I am using extjs 4.
The link below shows a diagram that shows extjs 4 does not support tablet and mobile. For this, they refer to Sencha touch:
https://www.sencha.com/blog/modus-create-ext-js-5-tablet-support/

Does this really mean there is no way of getting extjs 4 supporting tablets or mobile phones? Has anyone come up with a solution for this, with not too many hacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no "easy" way to add tablet support in Ext 4. Ext 5 had signifcant core portions rewritten to allow for gesture/touch management.